# Return value from "loop" for two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array.

```js
var citycode = [
  ["In Milan", 0],
  ["Rom", 5],
  ["Modena", 6],
  ["Others", 20]
];
```

How can I return value from For loop for this Array to have:

```
<div class="loop"><span>In Milan</span><span>0</span> </div>
<div class="loop"><span>Rom</span><span>5</span> </div>
....
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you need the space here `</span> </div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be pedantic but OP asked for for loop..

```
    var htmlContent = "";
            for (var i = 0; citycode.length > i; i++) {
              htmlContent += '<div class="loop"><span>' + citycode[i][0] + '</span><span>' + citycode[i][1] + '</span></div>'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for another option.

Comment: Yes, they wanted a for loop, but why run the loop backwards? This will reverse the order.

Comment: @GoneCoding sorry, old habits! Updated

Answer (score 2):

Using functional programming, without loops.

```js
var cityCode = [
  ["In Milan", 0],
  ["Rom", 5],
  ["Modena", 6],
  ["Others", 20]
];

const result = cityCode.map(code => 
  `<div class="loop"><span>${code[0]}</span><span>${code[1]}</span></div>`
).join('')

document.body.innerHTML = result;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var citycode = [
  ["In Milan", 0],
  ["Rom", 5],
  ["Modena", 6],
  ["Others", 20]
];



for (var i = 0; i < citycode.length; i++) {
  for (var o = 0; o < citycode[i].length; o++) {

    console.log(citycode[i][o])

  }


}
```

Use 2 for loop to get each item

Comment: It is helpful. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @MinhAnh glad to help mate :) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You could create DOM elements and append `body`.

```js
var citycode = [["In Milan", 0], ["Rom", 5], ["Modena", 6], ["Others", 20]];

citycode.forEach(function (city) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    city.forEach(function (a) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
        this.appendChild(span);
    }, div);

    this.appendChild(div);
}, document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is what I need.

Comment: jQuery would be a *lot* shorter (and this was tagged as a jQuery question).

Comment: @GoneCoding, feel free to answer the question, or edit mine.

Comment: No point. There are already shorter jQuery answers and not my place to change a JavaScript answer into a jQuery one. Just pointing out the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Array.prototype.reduce()` is ideal for these jobs. You may do functionally as follows;

You are basically expected not to work on DOM but on a document fragment and once finished with your job to append the document fragment to the correct place at the DOM all at once.

```js
var citycode = [["In Milan ", 0], ["Rom ", 5], ["Modena ", 6], ["Others ", 20]],
    mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
mainDiv.appendChild(citycode.reduce(function(p,c){
                                      var d = document.createElement("div");
                                      d.classList.add("loop");
                                      c.reduce(function(dv,sp){
                                                 var s = document.createElement("span");
                                                 s.textContent = sp;
                                                 dv.appendChild(s);
                                                 return dv;
                                               },d);
                                      p.appendChild(d);
                                      return p;
                                    },document.createDocumentFragment()));
```

```css
.loop {color: red}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: you stil maintain funny coding style ... ;)

Comment: @Nina Scholz If it's the indenting what you find interesting; I am pretty sure you can immediately tell where a function starts and ends. This indenting approach is especially more helpful with the functional programming where you have more nested functions, inline functions attached to the functors etc. I believe the days of [portrait IDE monitors](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/macbook-pro-with-portrait-mode-display.jpeg) are a matter of past for me. What i really need is in fact something like [this](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-25UM58-P-ultrawide-monitor) :)